# 3d plot with pgfplots and tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, pgfmath

[image]

Following coordinates:

1. `O(0|0|0)`
2. `P\left(-\frac{25}{2}|0| 0\right)`
3. `Q\left(-\frac{25}{2}|-12|9\right)`
4. `R(0|-12|9)`
5. `L\left(-\frac{25}{4}|-8| 6\right)`
6. `g: \vec{x}=\left(\begin{array}{c}0 \\ -12 \\ 9\end{array}\right)+r \, \left(\begin{array}{l}1 \\ 0 \\ 0\end{array}\right)`
7. strippled line `B_{t}\left(-5-3 t\left|-8 t+\frac{8}{3} t^{2}\right| 6 t-2 t^{2}\right)`

Source of the plot: https://fragdenstaat.de/anfrage/abitur-aufgaben-im-fach-deutsch-im-jahr-2020-in-schleswig-holstein/

Answer (score 1):

If you prefer to have only the drawing I have draw for you using [Mathcha](https://www.mathcha.io/editor) a MWE that it is similar to your picture.

```
  \documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
    \usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
    \usepackage{tikz}
 
    \begin{document}
    \tikzset{every picture/.style={line width=0.75pt}} %set default line width to 0.75pt        

\begin{tikzpicture}[x=0.75pt,y=0.75pt,yscale=-1,xscale=1]
%uncomment if require: \path (0,460); %set diagram left start at 0, and has height of 460

%Shape: Parallelogram [id:dp7638118196559391] 
\draw  [fill={rgb, 255:red, 155; green, 155; blue, 155 }  ,fill opacity=1 ] (319.17,58.69) -- (121.48,103.13) -- (226.02,254.74) -- (423.72,210.3) -- cycle ;
%Straight Lines [id:da6316488273872889] 
\draw    (224,305.11) -- (224,11.2) ;
\draw [shift={(224,8.2)}, rotate = 450] [fill={rgb, 255:red, 0; green, 0; blue, 0 }  ][line width=0.08]  [draw opacity=0] (10.72,-5.15) -- (0,0) -- (10.72,5.15) -- (7.12,0) -- cycle    ;
%Straight Lines [id:da731917802457239] 
\draw    (422.22,208.8) -- (167.24,265.62) ;
\draw [shift={(164.31,266.27)}, rotate = 347.44] [fill={rgb, 255:red, 0; green, 0; blue, 0 }  ][line width=0.08]  [draw opacity=0] (10.72,-5.15) -- (0,0) -- (10.72,5.15) -- (7.12,0) -- cycle    ;
%Straight Lines [id:da6576056173884619] 
\draw    (166,225.11) -- (382.8,325.85) ;
\draw [shift={(385.52,327.11)}, rotate = 204.92000000000002] [fill={rgb, 255:red, 0; green, 0; blue, 0 }  ][line width=0.08]  [draw opacity=0] (10.72,-5.15) -- (0,0) -- (10.72,5.15) -- (7.12,0) -- cycle    ;
%Shape: Parallelogram [id:dp5626379173953842] 
\draw  [fill={rgb, 255:red, 155; green, 155; blue, 155 }  ,fill opacity=1 ] (422.22,208.8) -- (224.24,252.94) -- (309.54,292.26) -- (507.52,248.11) -- cycle ;
%Straight Lines [id:da827548276907238] 
\draw  [dash pattern={on 0.84pt off 2.51pt}]  (34.52,123.11) -- (406.52,39.11) ;
%Shape: Arc [id:dp5174902423797783] 
\draw  [draw opacity=0][dash pattern={on 0.84pt off 2.51pt}] (319.65,232.63) .. controls (319.33,231.97) and (319.01,231.31) .. (318.7,230.65) .. controls (300.4,191.52) and (308.31,151.47) .. (336.38,141.21) .. controls (350.2,136.15) and (366.33,139.26) .. (381.33,148.39) -- (369.53,212.06) -- cycle ; \draw  [dash pattern={on 0.84pt off 2.51pt}] (319.65,232.63) .. controls (319.33,231.97) and (319.01,231.31) .. (318.7,230.65) .. controls (300.4,191.52) and (308.31,151.47) .. (336.38,141.21) .. controls (350.2,136.15) and (366.33,139.26) .. (381.33,148.39) ;
%Straight Lines [id:da8976458721984004] 
\draw    (422,200.11) -- (422,215.11) ;
%Shape: Circle [id:dp675535225833886] 
\draw  [fill={rgb, 255:red, 0; green, 0; blue, 0 }  ,fill opacity=1 ] (262.99,128.61) .. controls (262.99,127.78) and (263.67,127.11) .. (264.5,127.11) .. controls (265.33,127.11) and (266,127.78) .. (266,128.61) .. controls (266,129.44) and (265.33,130.11) .. (264.5,130.11) .. controls (263.67,130.11) and (262.99,129.44) .. (262.99,128.61) -- cycle ;
%Shape: Circle [id:dp5352551443676392] 
\draw  [fill={rgb, 255:red, 0; green, 0; blue, 0 }  ,fill opacity=1 ] (118.47,103.13) .. controls (118.47,102.3) and (119.14,101.63) .. (119.97,101.63) .. controls (120.8,101.63) and (121.48,102.3) .. (121.48,103.13) .. controls (121.48,103.96) and (120.8,104.63) .. (119.97,104.63) .. controls (119.14,104.63) and (118.47,103.96) .. (118.47,103.13) -- cycle ;
%Shape: Circle [id:dp48268828325901514] 
\draw  [fill={rgb, 255:red, 0; green, 0; blue, 0 }  ,fill opacity=1 ] (319.17,58.69) .. controls (319.17,57.86) and (319.85,57.18) .. (320.68,57.18) .. controls (321.51,57.18) and (322.18,57.86) .. (322.18,58.69) .. controls (322.18,59.52) and (321.51,60.19) .. (320.68,60.19) .. controls (319.85,60.19) and (319.17,59.52) .. (319.17,58.69) -- cycle ;

% Text Node
\draw (426,188.51) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]    {$-\frac{25}2$};
% Text Node
\draw (408,218.51) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]    {$P$};
% Text Node
\draw (272,120.51) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]    {$L$};
% Text Node
\draw (33,97.51) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]    {$g$};
% Text Node
\draw (111,79.51) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]    {$R$};
% Text Node
\draw (320,34.51) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]    {$Q$};
% Text Node
\draw (159,276.51) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]    {$x_{1}$};
% Text Node
\draw (356,323.51) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]    {$x_{2}$};
% Text Node
\draw (194,17.51) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]    {$x_{3}$};
\draw (204,260) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]    {$O$};


\end{tikzpicture}

    \end{document}
```

[image]